# JavaScript substr on jQuery html() of a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, substr

What I'm trying to ask is that when I take on a `.each` loop in jQuery using a build of a string by this:

```
$('.list :checkbox').each(function()
{
    var type = $(this).attr('value');
    Build += type + ', ';

    return Build;
});
```

But now I need to remove the last "," (without quotes) since it makes a list like this:

```
Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 4, Item 5,
```

Then it has to be added to the `html()` function which works well, but when trying to remove the last "," doesn't work by doing this:

```
Build.substr(-1);

$('#list-box').html(Build);
```

But that won't work.

Comment: Use `this.value` instead of `$(this).attr('value')`. It's faster and more readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@YouBook: Try

```
Build.substr(0, Build.length - 1);
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could simplify your code with something like this:

**(updated)**

```
var arr = $(":checkbox").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();


$('#list-box').html(arr.join(","));
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/rXB2K/ **(also updated)**

- Uses the [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function to translate the jquery results array to an array of checkbox values.
- Calls [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), separating each value with a comma.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use initial caps for variables.

Also, Strings are immutable in JS, so it's

```
   build = build.substring(0, b.length-1)
```

This is a general purpose function called `join` in most languages, you should break it out as a utility function.

You should take into account the possibility of a zero length list.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using substring instead of substr? e.g.

```
Build.substring(Build.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Build = Build.slice(0,-1);
```

works?

Answer (score 0):

Instead this:

```
return Build;
```

write this:

```
return Build.substr(0, Build.length-1);
```